# Randomly order menu-bar-lets?

Tags: menu-bar

I know it is impossibly to manage the order for the applets in the menubar (those which aren't apple's own). Yet is there an application or trick that enables this?

Eg. I have a calendar barlet that I would like to put to the left of apple's clock, and then apple's battery indicator, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no officially supported way to do this - the API that allows for them to be re-arragned is private. Some third party apps take advantage of this, some just use the officially provided status menu item API, which do not allow re-arranging. I know of at least one app that doesn't support re-arranging natively, but allows you to download a menu item which can be moved ([Fantastical](http://www.flexibits.com), by the way. Their FAQ has a link to the menu item).

In short, it's a mixed bag.

What I've used as a workaround is creating an automator action that launches all the apps with status items in the order I want. So, the first app to launch puts its item all the way on the right, and the subsequent apps add them to the left, in order. Then, I save this workflow as an application and add that to my login items. This doesn't allow you to mix/match official/non-official apps, but it works well enough for me.

Comment: Okay, great! I actually only needed to move fantastical (big coincidence). Leaves me wondering why other apps don't allow for this...